# How to convert a string json to a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple WinForm program that does a WebRequest to a server, the response is a string looking like:

```
{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}
```

How do convert this string to a dictionary? (`Dictionary<string, string>`). Is there a built-in function I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a library like [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(json)
```

Comment: Isn't that only for .net?

Comment: C# and winforms are both .NET concepts @ThomasWagenaar

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar C# ***is*** .NET

Answer (score 0):

```
var sourve = @"{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}";
Dictionary<string, string> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(source);
```

Comment: this is not correct=> var sourve = @"{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}";

Comment: What about that "{\"a\":\"foo\",\"b\":\"bar\"}" ?

Comment: what do you think ?check it in VS then ask me:)

Comment: This won't work out of the box, you need to add a reference to JSON.NET

Answer (score 0):

If you can add two assemblies:

- System.Web
- System.Web.Extensions

You can use this code:

```
string html = "{\"a\":\"foo\",\"b\":\"bar\"}";

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(html);
```